# Extracting an array of a member variable from a vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stdvector

Let's say I have a struct:

```
struct Foo {
  float A;
  float B;
  float C;
};
```

And I have a vector of the struct:

```
std::vector<Foo> vFoo;
```

And a function that takes arrays of floats (or whatever the same type as Foo members):

```
float foo_floats(const float a[], const float b[], const float c[]);
```

My question is, is there a way to use vFoo as arguments for foo_floats? In other words, is it possible to extract the arrays of A, B, and C in Foo from vFoo *without* creating additional vectors?

I want to get rid of the three new vectors (x, y, and z) in the following because clearly it is a waste of memory:

```
std::vector<float> x, y, z;
for (int i=0; i<vFoo.size(); ++i) {
  x.push_back(vFoo[i].A);
  y.push_back(vFoo[i].B);
  z.push_back(vFoo[i].C);
}
const float f = foo_floats(&x[0], &y[0], &z[0]);
```

Comment: Why isn't `foo_floats` taking a vector as arguments?

Comment: You can make `Foo` have a vector of 3 floats instead of separate ones.

Comment: The reason why 'foo_floats' does not take vectors as its arguments is because it is a function of an external library that does not use STL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use `vFoo` directly given those declarations, no. If you just wanted to avoid extra allocations you could transpose the data in-place (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition), but that's likely to be slower than transposing out-of-place. So your options are:

- Your current approach.
- Transpose in-place.
- Rewrite your code to make `vFoo` a structure of arrays (SoA) instead of an array of structures (AoS).
- Rewrite `foo_floats` to take an AoS instead of a SoA.
- Rewrite `foo_floats` to take a "stride" value for each of its input parameters, so that it is applicable to both AoS and SoA data.

Incidentally, if I had no control over `foo_float`, and were solely concerned with performance, I'd do the out-of-place transposition without a second thought. Rather than using three separate vectors, I'd use one, pre-sized to hold all three component arrays. If I were really REALLY worried about performance, I'd do it with SIMD intrinsics, transposing and scattering four (or eight) triples at once. You probably don't need to be that concerned about performance.